# Cookie isn't stored in cookie storage

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, cookies, fetch

I sent a request to get cookies like this

```
    let config = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "credentials": "include"},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: emailForm.value,
            password: passwordForm.value
        }),
    };
    fetch("https://be.workingtime.kro.kr/auth/login", config)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.code == 200) {
                console.log("access token : " + get_cookie("Authorization"));
            }
        });
```

So I received this response from server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OItdx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxHY5.png

But there is no cookie in the cookie storage

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmDlO.png

This is the server side code (Spring Boot)

```
    globalcors:
        add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: 'https://www.workingtime.kro.kr'
            allow-credentials: true
            allowedHeaders: '*'
            allowedMethods:
              - PUT
              - GET
              - POST
              - DELETE
              - OPTIONS
```

I allowed credentials both request and response, and set allowed origin.

Also the path of the cookie is /, the expiration date is not over, and SameSite=None; Secure to cookies for CORS.

What am I missing now? I thought the partition key of the cookie is weird.

Comment: I think you want the [credentials option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) to be set to "include", not some made up header called credentials. :p

Comment: Your cookie is for `be.workingtime.kro.kr` not for `www.workingtime.kro.kr`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Credentials : include is in the request header, so I thought it didn't matter. But I'll try it. thx!

Comment: `is in the request header` yes, that's what you are doing wrong. Sending a header that doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: @M.Deinum The domain of the cookie is be.workingtime.kro.kr, so it works for be.workingtime.kro.kr

Comment: YOu are showing the cookies (in your browser) for a different domain!